# how to implement connect button alongwith drizzle library for ethereum dapp?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, drizzle

I'm trying to create an ethereum dapp which uses drizzle library. I need to implement a connect button logic in which clicking on connect button will provide options like Metamask, WalletConnect, FortMatic etc. is it possible to implement such logic for connect button alongwith using DrizzleProvider or drizzleReactHooks.DrizzleProvider ?  been trying various options but no luck.